# method initializeFlipper in class MainApplication cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: android, react-native, build, upgrade, flipper

I'm trying to upgrade RN from 0.61.5 to 0.67.3 and while adding Flipper got an error: `initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());`. I can't find any info on how fix it.

**UPDATE**:
I deleted all changes connected to Flipper

Comment: What did you do with that line specifically in the MainApplication.java specifically to delete the flipper reference?